# Достать дочерний узел из firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview

Подскажите кто сталкивался, как можно добраться до дочернего узла (надеюсь я правильно назвал это) в firebase? Структура ветки firebase такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно добраться до узла "Photo" ну и далее выгрузить эти image в ячейки в collectionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам, может кому пригодится.

Немного другой пример, но суть такая же
Структура **firebase**:

```
posts
   post_0
     Photo
       image: "https://www....."
   post_1
     Photo
       image: "https://www....."
```

Код **swift**:

```
let ref = self.ref.child("posts")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Photo")
        let dict = imageSnap.value as! [String: Any]
        let url = dict["image"] as! String
        print(url)
     }
})
```